# Database Exception Flutter sqflite

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

i want to create multiple table like this

```
static Future<void> createTables(sql.Database database) async {
    await database.execute("""CREATE TABLE cart (
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
      food TEXT,
      price INTEGER,
      qty INTEGER,
      cashier TEXT,
      createdAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ) """);
    await database.execute("""CREATE TABLE transaction (
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
      no_nota TEXT,
      food TEXT,
      price INTEGER,
      qty INTEGER,
      cashier TEXT,
      createdAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ) """);
}
```

But after i build/run application, the application throws error

> Exception has occurred. SqfliteDatabaseException
> (DatabaseException(near "transaction": syntax error (code 1
> SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE transaction (
> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
> no_nota TEXT,
> food TEXT,
> price INTEGER,
> qty INTEGER,
> cashier TEXT,
> createdAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
> )) sql 'CREATE TABLE transaction (
> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
> no_nota TEXT,
> food TEXT,
> price INTEGER,
> qty INTEGER,
> cashier TEXT,
> createdAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
> ) ' args [])

how should i do ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Avoid reserved keywords in SQL or escape them**

The issue is with the table name you're trying to create. The word "transaction" is a reserved keyword in SQLite, which means you can't use it directly as a table name without escaping it properly.

It is either you change the table name or escape it like so `transaction`.. Consider the below code

```
    CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
  AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  no_nota TEXT,
  food TEXT,
  price INTEGER,
  qty INTEGER,
  cashier TEXT,
  createdAt TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Comment: Yes, i change table name and it works. Thank you Alex